# How do I ignore short documents with Sklearn?

Tags: scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I am using Sklearn's CountVectorizer() to transform my text document into an article-word co-occurrence matrix. 
It has worked great, however I want it to exclude rows corresponding to documents that contain less than k words.

I have attempted to do this via simple for loop however as I'm working with spare arrays it doesn't work. It isn't the most elegant code either - there must be a better way!

The code below finds the co-occurrence matrix X, the loop cycles through each row and checks if there are more than k words.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(doc)

for i in range(len(data)):
if sum(X[i,:])<k:
    count += 1
```

Comment: Do you mean sparse arrays ? 
If so, what actual data structure do you use ? Is it for example a scipy sparse matrix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of [getnnz](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.getnnz.html) as shown below:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(doc)
k = 100
X_reduced = X[X.getnnz(axis=1)>=k]
```